# Trying to figure out Google Cloud Platform quota/ GSuite support

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I am new to Google Cloud Platform.  I built an app that uses Google Sheets.  I have several scripts for the sheet.
I am having an error - `invoking too many times. URLfetch error.`, so I know I am calling the url too many times.  I need help:

1. How do I find out exactly how many url fetches I am calling.
2. If i need to add more calls, what Google suite subscription do I
   need to get?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you're mixing two different subjects here (API quota and some URLfetch error). Please edit you question to clarify what's your purpose and maybe separate different subjects into other question. In addition, explain better which GCP services are you working on.

Comment: Sorry.  I am referring to Quotas (URL fetch).  I have a google sheet that runs every minute (trigger).  It throws an error saying the urlfetch was invoked too many times in one day.  I looked this up and found that i get 20,000 per day as a FREE user. My questions are:   1. How do i find out excalty how many url fetches i am calling.  2. If i need to add more calls, what Google suite subscription do i need to get?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are developing [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

You can check the quota limits of App Script in the [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas),

It also points out the quota of `URL Fetch calls` is `20,000 / day` which you already knew.

To your question:

1. To my acknowledgment, there's no way to check how much daily quota has been used.
2. You can consider at least **G Suite basic** for `100,000 / day` quota.

If you need more than 100,000 / day, you'll need at least **G Suite Business** to apply for Early Access flexible quota.

Comment: Brent - Thank you so much for your response.  This helps a lot.  Thanks...